# AngularJS JSON Array with variable in the javascript tag

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I need variable to tag javascript from my JSON file. This is a part of my JSON file

```
[
{
    "title": "AfroEarth USA",
    "url": "us",
    "id": "50011",
    "country" : "US",
    "countryFlag": "img/flags/us-flag.png",
    "countries": [
        "AUSTRALIA",
        "CANADA",
        "SOUTH AFRICA",
        "UNITED KINGDOM",
    ],
    "countrieUrls": [
        "/au",
        "/can",
        "/sa",
        "/uk"
    ],
},
{
    "title": "AfroEarth UNITED KINGDOM",
    "url": "uk",
    "id": "50011",
    "country" : "UK",
    "countryFlag": "img/flags/uk-flag.png",
    "countries": [
        "AUSTRALIA",
        "CANADA",
        "SOUTH AFRICA",
        "UNITED STATES",
    ],
    "countrieUrls": [
        "/au",
        "/can",
        "/sa",
        "/us"
    ],
},....
```

This is a part of my controller

```
afroEarthApp.factory('Main', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('js/afromain.json',{})
}])
afroEarthApp.controller('afroEarthMainCtrl',['$scope','$http','$location','Main', function($scope, $http, $location, Main) {
        $scope.mainSite = Main.query();
}]);
```

And my html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="afroEarthApp">
<head ng-controller="afroEarthMainCtrl">
  <!-- Site Title -->
  <title>{{mainSite[0].title}}</title>
</head>
<body class="home-page" ng-controller="afroEarthMainCtrl">

  <ng-view></ng-view>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <!--Angular.js Route-->
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <!--Angular.js Resource-->
  <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <!-- WLD CAMPAIGN TRACKING -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var $element = $('[ng-controller="afroEarthMainCtrl"]');
      var scope = angular.element($element).scope().mainSite; // this is a problem
      console.log(scope); 
    });
    var wld_app_id =  312312;
    var wld_app_url = "us.afroearth.com";
  </script>
```

`<title>{{mainSite[0].title}}</title>` - this is works.
`var scope = angular.element($element).scope().mainSite;` - this is Array.
But when I want to get the first object.
`var scope = angular.element($element).scope().mainSite[0];` - this is undefind.
`var scope = angular.element($element).scope().mainSite[0].id;` - also didn't work

[My array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFBsq.jpg)

Comment: first, it's not really clear why you are trying to do this this way;  using `angular.element().scope()` should never be necessary.  Secondly, you can't access the variable this way anyway, since the return result is from an async `$resource` callback, and isn't available during `$(document).ready`.

Comment: I have futher script tag with js code for my backend - platform. And I need put to this variable `var wld_app_id ` ID from my JSON. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get that information before it is available, if that information is coming back from $resource that means it is only available way later after document.ready occurs.

Also you should definitely not be using `scope()` there, if you explain better what you're doing it would be easier to help, if you need some value of resource in a global variable outside of your angular components you can declare the variable there and assign a value to it once the information comes back.

Comment: I have a many similar pages. The differents it are country, id(for platform-backend), images, title and other. This ID I need for futher js code in the script tag. Why I get array with my data? But can't choice the element.

Comment: Because the array is coming after you tried to select the data.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ you need to be a lot more familiar with the event loop and asynchronicity

Comment: Thaks for video.I understood my problem. But I didn't find the way to solve it. I have two controllers. And the same js files(my old plugins and js file for backend). I use app.run to run at the two controllers. And I need put sone data from my controller(json) to this variable `var wld_app_id`. This variable I can put to the index.html or app.run. Can you help me. Because I'm at an impasse